# Why my gravatar has suddenly changed?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, gravatar

My gravatar has suddenly changed. I know this question has been asked before. However the only answer I found is that it could be due to a change in e-mail address or if I accessed my account from a different unusual location.

However, I did not do any of these, so I was wondering what might have caused this sudden change.

---

**Added by Arthur Fischer.**  I have looked at the email addresses associated with the user's "my logins" here (all the same), taken the MD5 hash, and then passed it on to Gravatar to see what results, which was this:
[image]
([Gravatar URL](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b07857fdaa9d16a1a1e822abd40c0d27?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)).  This matches the original Identicon (and that given on the user's other SE accounts).  I have no idea how the current Identicon is being generated.

Comment: The email address connected to your Gravatar is, I believe, the one associated with your OpenID provider (not the one in your user profile).  Has this changed?

Comment: But both the email-ids are same. I use the same email-id with OpenID as is there in my user profile. And like I said, I did not change anything.'

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, then.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you log in to a different Stack Exchange site (say, MathOverflow) does your Gravatar change there, too?

Comment: Thanks for the  Work. Yeah, that is my original gravatar. @ArthurFischer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fairly recent article on ArsTachnica, regarding how using [Gravatars can leak an email address](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/07/got-an-account-on-a-site-like-github-hackers-may-know-your-e-mail-address/) has prompted us to make some changes to how we produce the gravatar hash (under certain circumstances).

Looks like this happened here.

Comment: So this "new" technique is more secure? And does it mean that my Gravatar will keep changing periodically from now on?

Comment: @Vishal - not more "secure", but we salt before hashing, meaning that the hash no longer directly corresponds to the email address that was used to generate it. We will not be changing the salt either, so the gravatar should remain as it is.

Comment: Ok. But is there any way I can have my original gravatar back? I really came to like it.

Comment: @Vishal - sorry, but we can't change things on a person by person basis.

Comment: @Vishal: If you just want to use the same picture, copy the URL of the image I added to the question above, and use it as a "custom (gr)avatar".  (Even copying the Gravatar URL should work.)

Comment: Has Gravatar thought about doing something like this again, to move to a secure hash algorithm like SHA256? Even salted md5 can be inverted now.

Comment: did something like this happen again now? My gravatar just changed without me doing anything

Comment: It is possible, if you changed your email address. Look at your settings. I haven't worked at this company for over 2 years now, so no clue if anything changed.

Comment: I don't have permission to suggest an Edit to this post, so I'll note that people should read [this 2013 announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204540/202692) and [this 2023 announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123/202692) for context and updated details, respectively.